# Why my function treats (vector...) and '#(...) differently in Racket if both are vectors?

Tags: vector, racket

I am using vectors in Racket for the first time. Usually, I use lists.

The phenomena bellow intrigues me. If I call an expression in the REPL using the '# "notation" I get:

```
> (vector? '#((cons 3 4) #f #f #f #f #f #f #f #f #f))
#t
```

And if I do the same but with `(vector...)` as "pre-fix notation" I get:

```
> (vector? (vector (cons 3 4) #f #f #f #f #f #f #f #f #f))
#t
```

Now, comes the tricky point. I did a vector-assoc which is similar to assoc (built-in for lists). This is my function:

```
(define (vector-assoc val vec)
  (define (aux val vec counter)
    (cond [(= (vector-length vec) counter) false] 
          [(not (pair? (vector-ref vec counter))) (aux val vec (+ 1 counter))]
          [(= val (car (vector-ref vec counter))) (vector-ref vec counter)]
          [true (aux val vec (+ 1 counter))]))
    (aux val vec 0))
```

When I call vector-assoc  with `(vector...)` everything works fine:

```
> (vector-assoc 3 (vector (cons 3 4) #f #f #f #f #f #f #f #f #f))
'(3 . 4)
```

However, when I use `'#(...)` a problem occurs:

```
> (vector-assoc 3 #'((cons 3 4) #f #f #f #f #f #f #f #f #f))

. . vector-length: contract violation
  expected: vector?
  given: #<syntax:interactions from an unsaved editor:17:20 ((cons 3 4) #f #f #f #f #f #f #f #f #f)>
```

Why is this happening? Shouldn't it be the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote over `(cons 3 4)` is `(list 'cons 2 3)`. Use a quasiquote, unquote combination to not quote over it:

```
(vector-assoc 3 `#(,(cons 3 4) #f #f #f #f #f #f #f #f #f))
```

Edit: See comments.

Comment: `'(cons 3 4)` is _not_ `(list cons 3 4)`. `list` is a procedure and always evaluates its arguments, so in the `list` form `cons` is a _procedure_; in the quoted form `cons` is a _symbol_. `(car '(cons 3 4))` --> `'cons`, but `(car (list cons 3 4))` --> `#<procedure:cons>`. IAC, it is better to just use the `vector` form instead of quasiquotation in simple cases like this.

Comment: Ah yes, typo! I forgot to include the quote on `cons`. I have edited the answer. And I agree, I prefer using the vector form in simple cases like these but wanted to show that combination to clarify the concept for this answer.